# How to keep only the 2nd field of a line and print this line and the following line?

Tags: linux, bash, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a file in fasta format consisting of 2 lines:

- a first line starting with the sign >
- a second line with letters.
  I would like to keep only the 2nd field of the first line (comma separator) and keep the second line as it is.

I don't know what simple command to use? Can you help me ?

Input

```
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1,TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1,g.1,m.1 type:internal len:692 gc:universal TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1:2-2074(+)
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2,TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1,g.2,m.2 type:5prime_partial len:329 gc:universal TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1:2-988(+)
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
```

Desired output

```
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F',' 'NR % 2 { $0 = ">"$2 } { print }' input_file
```

- [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)
- Set separator to comma (`-F','`)
- `NR % 2` Preform the following on ODD lines only

  - `{ $0 = ">"$2 }` Set the line to '`>` + whats in **col 2**'
- `{ print }` print the complete result
- `input_file` path to input file

---

Output:

```
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target the lines that start with `>`:

```bash
awk -F ',' '/^>/ { $0 = ">" $2 } 1' file.fasta
```

Output:

```
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. I got the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed's *substitute* command and only apply the substitution on lines starting with an closing angle bracket. The substitution replaces everything up to the first comma with `>` and removes everything after the first comma, including the comma itself.

```
sed '/^>/{s/>[^,]*,/>/;s/,.*//}' file.fasta
```

Demo:

```
$ sed '/^>/{s/>[^,]*,/>/;s/,.*//}' <<FASTA
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1,TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1,g.1,m.1 type:internal len:692 gc:universal TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1:2-2074(+)
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2,TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1,g.2,m.2 type:5prime_partial len:329 gc:universal TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1:2-988(+)
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
FASTA
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g1_i1
LDSGALVQIHSNGIKHISDRVYEWVSDGIITHCACNPRQIVIATTNEIIYFELDINGQLNEYSERREMPAQVQAMALGPIPPSQVRSRFLAVTLSDQTVRIVSLDPQDCLQPLSMQALPATAESVCIIEASFGDDTYDTSLYLNIGLKNGVLLRTSLDSVTGDLSDTRTRYLGSKPVKLFRVIIANCPAILAVSSRSWLCYY
>TRINITY_DN80808_c0_g2_i1
LTLGRFATRLSDLFLVVGVSTSLILNPRVSNGGIFYTFAVEFYGSMKLQILHKTTVEEVPGAVLTFQGRIVAGVGNLLRVYEMGKQKLLRKCENKRIPSLI
```